# ASP.NET webforms - How to access local resource (.resx) in different project

Tags: asp.net, webforms, localization, app-globalresources

We have a project that has all of our web controls. In another project, is the "control host" that renders web controls as per user customization.

All of our web controls are localized. However, we need to access some of the string resources (e.g. control's display name) in the other project.

How do we access a local string resource from one project in another?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by having a project that is nothing but resource string definitions and referencing that as needed wherever.